# 10 digest() iteration reached error in login procedure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, angularjs-digest

This is my code to implement in my application a login procedure. The application has to verify the cookie set by the server and continue with the login procedure by redirect the user to canvas state. My issue is that I get the above mentioned error. Actually it works that is the login is made successfully but I would like to get rid of this error. I guess that the error should be in the $stateChangeStart but I don't know how to fix it. any idea?

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app', [
      'ui.router',
      'ngResource',
      'ngCookies',
      'app.login'
    ])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    })
    .run(function($rootScope, AuthService, RedirectService) {
      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {
        if (!AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
          // the user isn't authenticated
          event.preventDefault();
          // redirect to the server side
          RedirectService.redirectToAuth();
        }
      });
    });
})();




(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.login')
    .factory('AuthService', Auth);

  Auth.$inject = ['Cookie', 'Session'];

  function Auth(Cookie, Session) {

    return {
      login: function(params) {
        // here set the session with params passed by the server
        Session.create(params.id, params.data.id, params.data.make, params.data.name);
      },
      isAuthenticated: function() {
        // check cookie here set in the server side
        return Cookie.exist();
      }
    };

  }

})();


(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.login')
    .service('Cookie', Cookie);

  Cookie.$inject = ['$cookies'];

  function Cookie($cookies) {

    this.authCookie = $cookies.__cookie;

    this.exist = function() {
      return (this.authCookie ? true : false);
    };
  }
})();

(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.login')
    .factory('RedirectService', Redirect);

  Redirect.$inject = ['$window'];

  function Redirect($window) {

    return {
      redirectToAuth: function() {
        // redirect the user to the server for auth
        $window.location.href = "http://" + $window.location.host + "/auth/facebook";
      }
    };
  }
})();


(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.login')
    .controller('LoginController', Login);

  // here inject what function Login needs
  Login.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'AuthService'];

  function Login($rootScope, $scope, $state, $stateParams, AuthService) {

    var params = {
      id: $stateParams.userid,
      data: {
        id: $stateParams.modelid,
        make: $stateParams.modelmake,
        name: $stateParams.modelname
      }
    };

    $scope.login = function(params) {
      AuthService.login(params);
      // activate the canvas state
      $state.go('canvas');
    };

    // run the login function to set the Session user with data passed by the server
    $scope.login(params);
  }
})();
```

Comment: although it should able to fix, but I used 301 redirect from server side and I personally think its cleaner to hard reload the browser.

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: I use angular-fullstack generator - https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack/blob/master/app/templates/server/auth(auth)/auth.service.js#L70

Comment: It doesn't fix my problem. I have already redirect at the server side

Comment: I have found the issue. the issue reside in using window.location.href. have you any suggestion?

Comment: as far as I noticed ui-router hook those location changes, I don't know good way for it. I personally put those raw location.href changes inside setTimeout, but Its not angular way.

Comment: I have noticed that $state has the reload method but I need to pass it an url

Comment: Can you provide a link to a working example that produces this error, on jsfiddle or plnkr, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help a little more:

```js
/*
We are using the below urlRouterProvider.otherwise() because of:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/600
 */
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location) {
    var $state = $injector.get('$state');
    $state.go('login');
});
```

With this code you can still use the `otherwise()`, the disadvantage of using `when()` is that other unknown routes will not match. Above code solved all of our infinite loops.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue

```
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
```

caused all this issue.

removed it and replaced with when() solved the issue